# Como sumar las filas de una matriz que contiene valores random y luego imprimirlas al lado de cada fila? C#

Tags: c#, random, matriz

```
static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            Random Ram = new Random();
        
            int[,] arrayRandom = new int[4, 4];

            for (int f = 0; f < 4; f++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
                {
                    arrayRandom[f, c] = Ram.Next(1, 7);
                    Console.Write(arrayRandom[f, c] + " ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

            }
            
            Console.ReadKey(); 
       }
    }
}
```

Quiero que se imprima al lado de cada fila un = + la suma de esa fila, pero no se como deberia de solucionarlo :D

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Y cual es tu problema? no sabes sumar o que cosa no sabes hacer?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            Random Ram = new Random();
        
            int[,] arrayRandom = new int[4, 4];

            for (int f = 0; f < 4; f++)
            {
                int suma_fila=0;
                for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
                {
                     
                    arrayRandom[f, c] = Ram.Next(1, 7);
                    suma_fila = suma_fila + arrayRandom[f, c];
                    Console.Write(arrayRandom[f, c] + " ");
                }
                Console.Write(suma_fila);
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
            
            Console.ReadKey(); 
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :D